# How to run a command when sbt starts and keep the session active?

Tags: sbt

If we define `initialCommands in console += "1+1"` this will run after console is executed.

Is it possible to run a command after sbt starts, like `initialCommands in sbtStartup += "console"` to enter the console automatically?

I'd like to keep the session (after executing the command) active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/faq.html#how-can-i-take-action-when-the-project-is-loaded-or-unloaded

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/api/index.html#sbt.StateOps

```
onLoad in Global := {
  ((s: State) => { "console" :: s }) compose (onLoad in Global).value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Executing sbt launcher with a task or command on command line executes it after sbt is up and running. `sbt console` would give you what you're after yet sbt will shutdown after the task/command finishes (I can only suspect that was the intent of the OP).

Comment: Not in this case. The console command was just an example. It's for a sbt plugin, I want the command to be executed after sbt start. I don't sbt to close after the command is done.

Comment: Noted and the question has been updated. BTW, why do you think the requirement *"It's for a sbt plugin"* is important in your case? Would the approved solution be different otherwise?