# How to set up a task that gets always executed?

Tags: sbt

I have a task in a plugin which I’d like to always have run in project that use it - it validates some dependency versions according to our custom rules.

I don’t mind when it gets run, as long as it’s always run. It’s a task because I want to log output to the console and the only way I know how to do that is with streams.value.log.xxx, and that can only be called from within a task.

- I tried a task that depends on `(compile in Compile)` but that doesn’t get run if the user does `sbt test`
- I tried running the task directly with `runTask()` but that takes a main class
- I tried [onLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388592/how-to-run-a-command-when-sbt-starts-and-keep-the-session-active%20onLoad) but that takes `State => State` from which I can’t call the logger from
- I couldn't work out how to depend on the `update` command, but if the user never calls the update command it seems it won't work anyway.

How do I meet my requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I have not spent much thinking on the idea, but think using `shellPrompt` of type `AttributeKey[State => String]` might be of help. Since it's a mere `AttributeKey` it may not be able to execute tasks or commands, but once you refactor the task you may end up with something working fine.

```
> help shellPrompt
The function that constructs the command prompt from the current build state.
```

Whenever the prompt is built by the `shell` command that *Provides an interactive prompt from which commands can be run.* (see `help shell`) `shellPrompt` is queried to build the prompt.

I executed a very rudimentary test and it gave me the result you're after.

**build.sbt**

```
shellPrompt <<= ShellPrompt.buildShellPrompt
```

**project/build.scala** (just a copy of the relevant part)

```
val buildShellPrompt = Def.setting {
  (state: State) =>
    {
      val extracted = Project extract state
      import extracted._
      val currProject = currentProject.id
      println("Hello world - how are you doing today?")
      "%s:%s:%s> ".format(
        currProject, currBranch, (version in ThisBuild).value)
    }
}
```

The `println` line is executed whenever the prompt is built which means at every line execution, be it a task, command, or literally everything.

See [sbt-reference-project](https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/sbt-reference-project) for a complete example of a custom `shellPrompt`.